# boolean equivalent to NULL in PHP

Tags: php, null, boolean

is this the right syntax to check if a value is equivalent to NULL or not in PHP:

```
if($AppointmentNo==NULL)
```

?
I have tried it but it seems that it is not working.  Any suggestion for another syntax?

Thanks

Comment: This is the proper way.  What *is* `$AppointmentNo`?  `var_dump($AppointmentNo);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/is_null):

```
if(is_null($AppointmentNo)) {

// do stuff

}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`===`):

```
if($AppointmentNo === NULL) {
```

An [**example**](http://codepad.org/q5o5K6ug):

```
$foo = NULL;

if(is_null($foo)) {
    echo 'NULL';
} else {
    echo 'NOT NULL';
}
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php).

```
is_null($AppointmentNo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_null()`.

```
if (is_null($AppointmentNo))
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use `is_null()`.

```
if (is_null($AppountmentNo))
```